# Access singleton sharedInstance in Objective-C class from Swift class in combined project

Tags: objective-c, swift, singleton

I have an objective-C project in which I have added a Swift class.  I would like to access a shared instance of an Objective C class from my Swift code but I can't find any examples of how to do this.  Here are a couple examples of code in Objective-C to access shared Instances that I would like to perform from Swift:

```
//to get property
self.managedObjectContext = [myModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

//to get a string returned by a method in the sharedInstance

NSString *aUser = [[referenceClass  sharedInstance] getUserName];
```

In the Objective-C header file for the singleton, I have

```
+ (referenceClass*)sharedInstance;
```

I have imported the classes needed such as referenceClass in my Bridging Header file but how would I get the string using Swift?

Something like:  (Pseudo code)

```
 var username: String = referenceClass.sharedInstance().getUserName()
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It compiles but throws exception at runtime

Comment: Any reason you keep down voting my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your singleton class reference variable as like this

```
var singletonReference = YourSingletoneClass.sharedInstance() as! YourSingletoneClass
```

and access value using reference variable

```
var username: String = singletonReference.getUserName()
```

According to your example you can use also like this

```
var username: String = (referenceClass.sharedInstance() as! referenceClass).getUserName()
```

**Note** : If you want your reference variable through out your class declare globally

Comment: Thanks, that did the job!  FYI, Fix-it changed code slightly to: let username: String = (referenceClass.sharedInstance()!).getUserName()